# How to compare all the variables in two different Eclipse sessions

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, eclipse-jdt

I am presently trying to find a bug in a long java code. This code reads an input text file and it runs many CFD simulations and then it collects results and analyzes them. In the input file there is a flag that only changes the order in which that bunch of completely independent threads is run. However, if I change this flag I have that the java program crashes after all the simulations are run, while it should actually behave the same. In order to debug this, I opened two different Eclipse sessions, and in each session I run the code. The only difference between the 2 sessions is the value of that flag I mentioned above. I have set up a breakpoint in a line after all the 37 threads (i.e. simulations) are run and results saved on file. That line is in a subroutine where only the main thread is active (all the other threads stopped) and it  collects and elaborate further the results of the 37 simulations. I would like to have a way to quickly compare all the variables (in the present scope) of one Eclipse session with the other, in order to find possible differences. Saving them in a text file and comparing the 2 text files would make the trick for me. Do you know how I can do it, if even possible at all? Any other working solutions is also welcomed.